# tailwind 3.0.23 classes not being applied in real time in storybook

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, storybook, postcss

not able to apply tailwind classes via storybook UI in real time, for example, changing the color of a button through the props `classes` here from `bg-red-600` to `bg-red-100` doesn't change the color of the button in the storybook ui, is it possible to change the color of the button from the UI to see what it would look like? (component works as expected in app, just not in the storybook)

not sure if this is related to purging or JIT compilation https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/6347

`storybook ui`

[image]

`button component`

```
<button
      type="button"
      className={clsx(
        "rounded-full py-2 px-3",
        classes,
        disabled ? "disabled:opacity-25" : ""
      )}
      onClick={onClick}
    >
```

`tailwind.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

`button.stories.tsx`

```
ButtonComponent.args = {
  label: "Button",
  classes: "bg-red-600",
  disabled: false,
};
```

`preview.js`

```
import "!style-loader!css-loader!postcss-loader!tailwindcss/tailwind.css";
import "../styles/globals.css";

export const parameters = {
  actions: { argTypesRegex: "^on[A-Z].*" },
  controls: {
    matchers: {
      color: /(background|color)$/i,
      date: /Date$/,
    },
  },
};
```

`main.js`

```
module.exports = {
  stories: [
    "../components/**/*.stories.mdx",
    "../components/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)",
  ],
  addons: [
    "@storybook/addon-links",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials",
    {
      name: "@storybook/addon-postcss",
      options: {
        cssLoaderOptions: {
          // When you have splitted your css over multiple files
          // and use @import('./other-styles.css')
          importLoaders: 1,
        },
        postcssLoaderOptions: {
          // When using postCSS 8
          implementation: require("postcss"),
        },
      },
    },
  ],
  framework: "@storybook/react",
  staticDirs: ["../public"],
};
```

`package.json` dev dependencies

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.17.7",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.17.0",
    "@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss": "^4.1.3",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.5.0-alpha.51",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.5.0-alpha.51",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^6.5.0-alpha.51",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.5.0-alpha.51",
    "@storybook/addon-postcss": "^2.0.0",
    "@storybook/react": "^6.5.0-alpha.51",
    "@storybook/testing-library": "^0.0.9",
    "@testing-library/dom": "^7.30.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
    "@testing-library/react": "^10.4.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.21",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.40",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.4",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.3",
    "clsx": "^1.1.1",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "eslint": "8.4.1",
    "eslint-config-next": "^12.1.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-storybook": "^0.5.7",
    "faker": "^5.4.0",
    "history": "^5.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "imports-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "jest-axe": "^6.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "postcss": "^8.4.12",
    "postcss-import": "^14.1.0",
    "storybook-addon-next": "^1.6.2",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.0.23",
    "typescript": "^4.2.4"
  },
```

Comment: Do you have a tailwind.config.js file?

Comment: @RicardoCosta yup, just added it to the post

Comment: Is your storybook components located under one of the paths inside content param in tailwind config file? It's also possible (but I am not really sure about this one) the wildcard can't reach the stories component and you might have to adapt the rule to be able to reach .stories.tsx

Comment: yea the components are inside the `components` folder, i'm not sure how the storybook and tailwind work in real time to apply the class change

Comment: You should be able to inspect element and see if the color class is actually doing anything (if it gives a value to the css class) if not then most likely it is being purged by tailwind and you need to add the stories path in the tailwind content array (look at my edit on previous comment)

Comment: the class is added but no value is given to the css, so it does seem like it's being purged, i added `    "./components/**/*.stories.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}"` to the content array but that didn't help, the stories file is in the same folder as the component file

Answer (score 12):

There is a config in tailwind called safelisting.
This option said that tailwind classes don't apply when they change in real time and DOM.

read: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes

you need to add specific classes to safelist to apply for changing in DOM and real-time.
you can add all of tailwind classes to safe list by adding this config to your `tailwind.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  safelist: [
    {
      pattern: /^(.*?)/,
    },
  ],
  // ...
}
```

Comment: thank you SO SO much! searched 2h for this

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't imagine why it doesn't work.. never would come up with this by myself

Comment: This was extremely helpful. Has anyone found a good way to only safelist for Storybook so we don't have to safelist our entire app? As they say in the Tailwinds docs, safe listing is a last resort. Thanks again though for revealing this fix!